# SQL Developer Where Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables for Sales, Vehicles and Customers and I am trying to create a query that will give the most sold vehicle make with the first and last names of customers that bought that type of vehicle. I created the following as a subquery to find the vehicle sales in descending order:

```
SELECT Vehicles.Vehicle_Make,
COUNT(Sales.VIN) AS NumberOfSales 
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Sales.VIN = Vehicles.VIN 
GROUP BY Vehicles.Vehicle_Make
ORDER BY NumberOfSales DESC;
```

The Customers and Sales tables share the common Cust_ID Column from which I can get the Customers First and Last names. Since the first row would give me the most sold vehicle make, how would I query to get just the first row and join the results from this subquery to the Customers table to get the first and last names?  Thank you for your advice in advance.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: `TOP 1` for SQL Server and `LIMIT 1` - mySQL with an appropriate `ORDER BY` for both

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 Vehicles.Vehicle_Make,
COUNT(Sales.VIN) AS NumberOfSales 
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Sales.VIN = Vehicles.VIN 
GROUP BY Vehicles.Vehicle_Make
ORDER BY NumberOfSales DESC;

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select c.*
from (
  select top 1
      vehicles.vehicle_make
    , count(sales.vin) as numberofsales 
  from sales 
    inner join vehicles 
      on sales.vin = vehicles.vin 
  group by vehicles.vehicle_make
  order by numberofsales desc
  ) t
  inner join vehicles v
    on v.vehicle_make = t.vehicle_make
  inner join sales s
     on s.vehicle_vin = v.vehicle_vin
  inner join customer c
     on c.cust_id = s.cust_id
```